# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 1' while taking input

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking multiple user inputs in one line using the following code -

```
X1,Y1 = int(input()).split()
X2,Y2 = int(input()).split()
X3,Y3 = int(input()).split()
```

but I am getting an error stating - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 1'

The input provided by the user is - 0 1

If anyone knows the issue it'll be really helpful
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you can't split an `int` into a list. You can try this:

```py
X1,Y1 = map(int, input().split()) # will return a list of int
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: can be achieved without  list

Answer (score 1):

```
X1,Y1 = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Comment: can be achieved without  list

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the split function upon the integer

Try this instead

```
X1,Y1 = map(int,input().split())
```